# 20.04 does not recognize my printers

Tags: drivers

updated to 20.04 now my printers don't work  I have a office jet 3830 and a 
laser jet pro mfp m26nw  I did the terminal install but it can not find 4 optional and 1 required setting

Comment: Please add output of `which hp-toolbox` and `dpkg -l | grep hplip` to the question.

Comment: i had problems with my printer got an error message comunication failed updated to latest kernel and this solved it for me.